# Dynamically insert into SQLite from text file

Tags: c#, sqlite, console-application

I am trying to create dynamical insert statements from text file, with only SQLite.

What I have done so far, is to create the SQL query with necessary parameters, add those parameters during run time, and try to select.

However I get error inside try block, when try to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

> Caught exception: SQL logic error or missing database
>   near "@0": syntax error

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestApp

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           //To store the index and column name in the file
           Dictionary<int, string> Columns = new Dictionary<int, string>();
           char[] delimiterChars = { '\t' };
            string createQuery = @" create table if not exists products(id integer not null primary key, name text);
                                insert into products (name) values ('A');
                                insert into products (name) values ('B');
                                insert into products (name) values ('C');
                                insert into products (name) values ('D');
                                insert into products (name) values ('E');
                                insert into products (name) values ('F');
                                insert into products (name) values ('G');
                                create table if not exists orders(id integer, dt datetime, product_id integer, amount real);"; 
        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("myDB.db3");
        using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=myDB.db3")){
            using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn)){
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = createQuery;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"../../../App_Data/import.txt");
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO orders (";
                // Identify the column order from first row of the import file
                string[] elements = lines[0].Split(delimiterChars);
                for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
                {
                    Columns[i] = elements[i];
                    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText + "@COLUMN" + i + ", ";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN" + i, Columns[i]);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(i + " : " + Columns[i]);

                }
                cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Remove(cmd.CommandText.Length - 2);
                cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText + ") VALUES (";
                string temp = cmd.CommandText;
                System.Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of Import File.txt = ");
                for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = temp;
                    elements = lines[i].Split(delimiterChars);
                    for (int j = 0; j < elements.Length; j++)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText + "@VALUE" + j + ", ";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALUE" + j, elements[j]);
                    }
                    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Remove(cmd.CommandText.Length - 2);
                    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText + ")";
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Caught exception: " + ex.Message);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
                    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
                }

                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from orders";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader["ID"] + " | " + reader["dt"] + " | " + reader["product_id"] + " | " + reader["amount"]);
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

I am not sure on what am I doing wrong?

The import.txt file consists of

```
id  dt  amount  product_id
1   2017-02-01T10:01:12 343.33  1
2   2017-02-01T10:02:12 12  2
3   2017-03-01T10:03:12 344.3   1
4   2017-04-01T10:04:12 12  3
5   2017-05-01T10:05:12 66.5    1
6   2017-06-01T10:06:12 4
```

All items divided by TAB

Comment: The first problem is the fact that your file doesn't contain the column names in the first line. So your first for...loop is wrong

Comment: Then, your file columns are separated by spaces not by tabs. (But this could just be the copy you pasted in the Stack Overflow editor) Check if your data is really tab separated

Comment: @Steve actually column names are there it is just mistake on my part (didn't formatted it correctly), I have edited it now, and tabs are present for sure

Comment: All right then, now the last row of your file is missing the product_id/amount value. Is this just a typo or do you really have a variable number of columns to insert?

Comment: However you already know the name of the columns from the previous Create Table command, so the loop to read the column names is useless, you can just skip the first row

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint in at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` in your `try` block and post the value of `cmd.CommandText`? Seeing the query would be helpful.

Comment: @Steve it is not a typo, it is done deliberately, I will add some extra control of the corrupted data. As for now all the insert statements return that error in the question. That table creation in the beginning is just for easy use.

Comment: @Poosh inside `cmd.CommandText` is `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO orders (@COLUMN0, @COLUMN1, @COLUMN2, @COLUMN3) VALUES (@VALUE0, @VALUE1, @VALUE2, @VALUE3)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop over the column names is useless because you already know the column names from the CREATE TABLE ORDERS command executed at the first lines.
By the way, you cannot use parameters to express the name of a column.
This is not allowed in any kind of database system that I know of.

You can safely remove it but note that you have declared the column order wrongly. In the CREATE TABLE you have

```
create table if not exists orders(
id integer, dt datetime, product_id integer, amount real
```

while in the file the *product_id* is the last column. So you need to adapt your CREATE TABLE to your file

```
create table if not exists orders(
id integer, dt datetime, amount real, product_id integer;
```

Next your insertion loop code could be rewritten in this way (ignoring the variable number of arguments as you explain)

```
string baseQuery = "INSERT INTO orders (id, dt, amount, product_id ) VALUES(";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"e:\temp\orders.txt");

// Skip the first line
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] elements = lines[i].Split(delimiterChars);

    // Keep the parameter names in a list to get an easy way to 
    // concatenate them all together at the end of the loop
    List<string> text = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < elements.Length; j++)
    {
        text.Add("@VALUE" + j);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALUE" + j, elements[j]);
    }
    // Create the command text in a single shot
    cmd.CommandText = baseQuery + string.Join(",", text) + ")";
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Consider also to enclose your database code inside a transaction like this as suggested by the link posted below by Alexander Petrov

```
using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=myDB.db3"))
using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
{
     conn.Open();
     using(SQLiteTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
     {
         cmd.Transaction = tr;
         .....
         for(....)
         {
             .....
         }
         tr.Commit();
     }
}
```

Comment: you are right, it seems like I cannot use parameters for the columns, that is why in the loop that is responsible for `INSERT INTO orders (` I have removed the parameter adding and used `cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText + elements[i] + ", ";` instead, which solved the problem. Thanks sir

Comment: INSERT in sqlite is very slow. So, I think, in this case, there is a reason to [wrap all inserts](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q19) in a single transaction. @Hatik

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov good point. Having a transaction here could speeds things up

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov then if in one insert some exception occurs, all the data will be rollbacked? or it will it ignore it and continue

Comment: If you catch the exception inside the for, the code continues with the following insert, but if you put the try/catch around the for loop then everything will be rolled back. The rollback will happen if you exit the transaction using block without a commit